# Mock a PART of EF DbContext with Moq and/or InMemoryDbSet

Tags: c#, entity-framework, integration-tests

This question is **NOT** about what's here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960192/mocking-ef-dbcontext-with-moq and/or similar questions. I am well aware of that. Please, read the question before replying. Thanks.

1. We have a fairly complicated database, which has some, call them, "business objects" (transactional data) and some, call them, "data objects" (operational data). The "business objects" are usually created or updated with every new user request and the "data objects" are fairly stable but may be occasionally created during user request if missing at the first call.
2. I want to create integration tests in the **sand box** where I could pull the *data objects* out of the real database (because there are too many of them to mock) but control what happens with the *business objects*. For example, if I have a `get or create` workflow (with some validation, of course), then I want explicitly test that **whole workflow** after testing separately `get` or `create` workflows in some other tests. However, if I test `get or create` workflow, then with the real DB I can only test `create` part of workflow once but then I will only hit a `get` workflow (because the object will exist after the first test run). Throw in that many tests are routinely run in parallel and the results become unpredictable.

I wonder what is the proper approach to perform a **partial** "mock" of a database context where most of the tables would come from the real DB but a few tables could be setup per test, e.g. in `InMemoryDbSet`s.

Comment: Would it be possible to have two databases, one with data objects and the other with business objects? The production code would just happen to use the same connection string for both databases.

Comment: In theory yes, but in practice no :( . All the the databases have been already designed and went live a while ago. So now we have that DB with some business (transactional) objects and some data (operational) objects. That's why I have this question.

Comment: Why not just copy the live database and do your sandbox testing in the copy?

Comment: @KonstantinKonstantinov, what I meant is that the software treats the data as if it resides in two different databases. This should be possible if you don't need to make joins between tables with business objects and tables with data objects. That it is actually deployed as a single DB is then irrelevant.

Comment: @candied_orange It is too much to copy - the "empty" database (== no transactional data but all operational data are fully populated) is about 7 GB.

Comment: @KonstantinKonstantinov 7 GB? Sheesh a $5 thumb drive is bigger than that.

Comment: We have 5,000+ integration tests. I cannot copy 7GB 5,000+ times to create a sandbox for each test.

Comment: Even that's only 35TB. I have that at home. But do you have to run all 5000 at exactly the same time? When a test is run that needs a sandbox DB give it an fresh copy not a used one. Keep a set of fresh ones ready to go and remember that renaming a 7GB file is fast even if copying and deleting one is not. Anyway this is straying from your original question which was was about creating new tests.

Comment: You also might want to look into creating real [Unit Tests](https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=126923) that can be run simultaneously without touching the DB at all. If you're using them I'm not sure how you ended up with 5000+ integration tests. Seems a bit much.

Comment: @candied_orange We have over 13K tests of which there are around 4K unit tests, around 5K integration tests, and the rest is are acceptance tests and various web tests. Last time I checked the source of this open source project: https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/ , it had over 20K tests. So, if you have something on the essence of the question, please, do comment. Otherwise, may I kindly ask you to refrain from further comments. Thanks!

Comment: @KonstantinKonstantinov I'm pressing you for an explanation of why you have to solve the problem the way you are attempting precisely because you question doesn't contain enough information to justify this approach. You have since clarified by adding more detail in comments. Such clairifying details belong in the question, not comments. Kindly put them there.

Comment: @KonstantinKonstantinov do so and I'll gladly delete these comments as they will no longer be needed.

Answer (score 1):

The most practical method I have seen is to use database snapshots to create and revert a real database.

here is an article on the subject:

https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/2007/07/06/60250/

Setup your database for the test or a set of tests and store the snapshot. Before running the tests use the snapshot to create the DB. When they care complete you can delete or revert the database as required.

You do not want to try to mock entity framework objects. For most purposes you should create a repository layer and mock that. But it sounds like this would be too much refactoring for you.

I note your comments on the size of the DB. Ideally you want to make your snapshot contain only the data needed for a single test. But you will have to judge the effort involved between manually setting up many small versions of the DB for each test vs larger 'copied from live' versions that can be used for large blocks of tests

Comment: Yeah. That's a good idea but I doubt that it would fly in our case :( . We run these 5k+ integration tests in parallel because otherwise they will take forever. If all of them are run in parallel, then they "want" to consume up to 30 GB of RAM for tests and additional about 10 GB of RAM for SQL, while having 1K+ simultaneous SQL connections. I have serious doubts that rolling back snapshots will work in this scenario. I have an idea, which is not as perfect as rolling back a snapshot, but it might still allow creating a near sand box experience. If it works, I will post it here.

Comment: ... addressing your main comment: yes, unfortunately refactoring the db / repo layer is beyond my control and without that the idea of mocking the repo simply won't work. Throw in that transactional data are interwoven with operational data and that all :(

Comment: Hmm it sounds like you have a very intense testing setup. If they literally need that much data to run, there's no getting around it regardless of what mocking you do. Maybe try splitting them over several machines?